# IPS Back on Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

A while back I remember IPS (Interpersonal Skills) [being removed from Hot Network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha).

To my surprise, just now I saw an IPS post on Hot Network Questions
[image]

Is IPS back on the list?

Comment: sshhhhh, they mustn't know

Comment: [Yes](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/lets-go-back-to-hnq?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is on-topic here. It is clearly about Stack Overflow. The “hot network questions” list is displayed in the sidebar on nearly every page on Stack Overflow. It makes sense that Stack Overflow users would have this question.

Comment: Ooooh, boy. It's right and just that they're back, given the daft and sexist motives behind the original removal. Let's just hope that the Twitter feminists who got it banned in the first place don't notice, or no longer care - since if they do, their anger will once again be directed at us, and we'll get to have another round of culture war conflict we don't need.

Comment: ...Didn't we used to have a close reason to migrate questions to Meta.SE? Where did it go? @CodyGray Seems like a foolish consistency. The question is clearly much better suited for Meta.SE since it affects all sites, and it has nothing to do with SO itself.

Comment: It's been a while already: [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/21808/how-to-let-other-coworkers-know-that-i-dont-share-my-coworkers-political-views) became hot on May 21.

Comment: @jpmc26 There's never been such a close reason, and there won't be. Moderators can migrate to MSE when absolutely necessary, but questions about the network at large can *always* be asked on one of the child metas. This has been the situation since the very beginning and is *not* a reason to close. We do not require members of a particular site (e.g., SO) to even know about the existence of the global meta. They are welcome to ask about any problems they're having on the network on the meta site that they are familiar with. Staff members monitor all meta site, including child metas.

Comment: @CodyGray I fail to see how migrating a question to a more appropriate venue is undesirable, or how doing so "requires" anyone to know anything ahead of time anymore than requiring asking things on the site Meta does. HNQ is not a site feature. It's a global service. It just makes more sense.

Comment: @jpmc26 But this question *is* about Stack Overflow. We, specifically, were the catalyst for IPS's ban from HNQ; it was premised on the idea that showing question titles about unwanted female sexual advances *in a forum for programmers* was wrong because it alienates female programmers, and that *Stack Overflow* needed to get rid of those titles in order for us to stop being sexist. As such, it is Stack Overflow specifically, not any of the other network sites, who stand to suffer the reputational consequences of IPS being restored. It matters much to us, and little to the rest of the network.

Comment: @jpmc26, I use SO, and sometimes a few others. I really don't want to add SE or MSE to the list of sites I need to keep track of. this chain of "where this belongs" is *unbelievably* meta. the meta-ist of metas.

Comment: @MarkAmery No, we weren't. Some random Twitter user who promotes a competitor was. The community in general largely disagreed strongly with the change.

Comment: @jpmc26 Meh, semantics. I'm well aware that the community disagreed with the change; my point is that the Twitter user cared about the questions being shown *on Stack Overflow*, because that tied into the wider narrative about Stack Overflow specifically being "unwelcoming" to women. If the titles were only visible on the other Stack Exchanges, the Twitterer wouldn't have cared (and neither would the staff). That is the sense in which I mean that we were the catalyst.

Comment: @MarkAmery The criticism was complete nonsense to begin with, [leveraged by someone who told SO users "Go away" and called them annoying](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/1052322898252304384) when they left a message explaining they had tried to improve the title under complaint. Clearly, the complaint came from someone who has no concept of what "welcoming" means. You're giving the original complaint far more credit than the evidence lends it. They would have found something else to complain about regardless. SO has never been unwelcoming to women. The complaint should have been disregarded.

Comment: @MarkAmery The point being: no, it doesn't matter to SO specifically, because it never mattered in the first place. Except to the *staff*, and their misguided opinions are just as detrimental to the entire network as they are to SO.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Catija, a CM for Stack Exchange, [removed IPS from the public facing "restricted from HNQ" list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316906/revisions).

So...maybe?

Comment: IPS back on HNQ, Makoto back on MSO... Oh boy, this week is a happy one.

Comment: "Back" is a strong word...

Comment: @Makoto - We'll take all the Makoto that Makoto gives.

Answer (score 12):

The [announcement that mods now have more ability to remove questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt) says...

> Yes, I've avoided mentioning IPS in this question. If you're interested in that site in relation to the HNQ, please see their meta. The TL;DR there is: if they want back in, they can get back in but it's up to them.

IPS discussed this on their meta and [seemed to indicate](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/revisiting-hnq-participation-for-ips) that they wanted to return. So I guess they are back because they wanted to be back.

Comment: The followup Meta IPS [Let's go back to HNQ!](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3642/3516) was marked status completed as well with a couple more [rules](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3648/3516), such as, questions mush reach a certain age before being eligible for HNQ from that site, and only 1 question from IPS may be in HNQ at a time.

Comment: @DavyM just a clarification, but the "certain age" rule is not only applied on IPS, but 8-hour globally on all sites.