# New Anonymous Tags feature to Votes(on post's not comments)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wanted to know if it's possible to introduce Tags that you get to choose while you are voting on a post.I mention this again on posts and not on comments. Because that will make messier. 
So the whole idea is to introduce tags that can be put up while voting on a post. These tags can be added ***anonymously*** by users.

**Usage**
These tags can be used to get an idea about the post  by the community that has already read/ invested time on the post and has an idea to what this post is about. Instead of directly reading the question posted by the user.It will tell you what to  This will also improve your knowledge and understanding of the question. And will save you time from reading multiple discussion threads that the post has for  example answers and different comment threads.
 Secondly, it can also allow minor feedback as these tags can give a sense as to what direction to be looked to improving the question. Thus by looking at this tag the person asking the question can go read that particular section where he is lacking.

**Functionality/features**

1. Can be added anonymously.
2. One Tag can be added to a post once only. Hence removing the possible chances of spamming.
3. Moderators can edit these tags. They can even be flagged(Optional
   feature).
4. When a tag is found wrongly used user can be punished in the background. Or the tag can be remove from being further used.
5. Already existing set of tags can be used to regulate the data.
6. Users can add/remove their own tags (Like if the post is improved and is now a question worthy of being asked you can remove negative tags)
7. Saves new users the headache of not knowing where the question went wrong.

   Like reason for upvote can have tags like `#new #conceptual #tricky` whatever and downvotes could have `#uncleancode #images #typos #repeatedquestion #vagueQuestion` etc .That do not mess with the code but add some info on top/bottom where person reading the post can read before reading the question and these can remain anonymous and can be edited by higher rep people.

Comment: Please don't use comments to elaborate upon your question. Use the "edit" feature. At any rate, this feature is very unlikely to be implemented. We decided a long time ago that "meta" tags like those you describe are not useful. Tags should only describe the contents of the question itself. Nobody wants to sort by all questions that are "tricky" or involve "typos", for example.

Comment: @CodyGray deleted them fine? Nobody is asking developers to sort questions by such tags. Asking developers to include them to increase the readability of posts

Comment: Also , these are just examples , you can always come up with better ones

Comment: related discussion at MSE - [Tell answer-author when the question is being voted to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322503/165773)

Comment: Still not sure I see the point. What value does this add to the site? How do we moderate it?

Answer (score 20):

These tags wouldn't describe the question.  They'd describe our opinions about the question.

I don't think I would gain much value from having someone's opinion of a question when I'm just looking to leverage the answers attached to the question.  I also wouldn't gain anything from seeing that someone felt like this question was "interesting" when all I really care about is wiring up my SPI to use the correct subsystem.

Also, I see room for abuse...

[image: #iamtherealestmoderatoryouhaveevermetinyourlife]

Comment: Again the example tags i used were just examples. You can always come up with better ones.(2) Edited before you can put it out here. But yeah feel free to report me if thats you wish for or whatever the procedure is IDK. I felt something i wrote about it. Not upto me to decide what happens next. But thank you. You atleast had a response. With others downvoting and leaving. Coz i  just realised that this question won't even reach the people who are actually capable of make these kinda changes to happen i guess.

Comment: My question is: do upvotes or downvotes describe the questions??? i believe every thing has little little parts to contribute. And roles to fullfil. If this was an existing feature you would have said "thank god this tag saved me from reading irrelevant/vague/broad/unanswerable question of 1000 words"

Comment: @AshishKumar: I don't have to report you - there's nothing to report.  I just found it humorous that #fakemoderators was used.  Anyway...you should take from this that you are empowered to make suggestions that can impact the site, but the users of the site are also equally empowered to disagree with those suggestions.  Suggestions which take into account the history and background of the site along with a clear explanation of what actual, tangible problem is being solved have a better chance of being received well.

Comment: @AshishKumar - to address the upvote/downvote thing:  vote score directly impacts a question's visibility on the site.  If a question is poorly received, it's hidden from the main page and tag pages.  So, it does matter; a question that the community decides to downvote means that fewer people will waste their time with it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported  i just started reading this and realized even you aren't happy with the community one way or the other. At this point in the SO how much do you think can be improved like in interface  and stuff?  Only small small changes can be added. I just suggested one. Being noobs thats what i have to offer. Why don't people who dislike find something better? Or make this into something that can matter or leave it visible that some day some one can!!!!!!!

Comment: Fine.  Don't take my advice.  I'll note this down for the future.

Comment: @AshishKumar That last comment is not only an _ad hominem_ argument, it also shows that you can't be tolerant to the fact that other people may disagree with your ideas. We are in the right not to appreciate certain suggestions, so long as it's done respectfully, just as Makoto did here.

Comment: @Ashish and, considering how combative you are when people nicely explain why they disagree with you (on a *meta* post, with no impact to rep)... Do you understand why people aren't really thinking going to give even MORE things for OPs to fight and combat and b*tch about is a good idea.